# executing command with ssh causes bash shell script loop to terminate

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

This script should call `ls` on the remote host N times, where N is the number of lines in the file `file-name`. For some reason it always runs once and then exits. If I change `f` to do something else (print a number, print the line of the file, etc) it works as expected and `f` is called N times. When I'm using `ssh` to execute a remote command, it only runs once. I did notice that changing the loop to no longer read input from the file seems to fix the issue, but I'd like to try and fix it a different way (I need to read the file).

```
function f() {
    ssh -i key user@host ls
}

while read line; do
  f
done<file-name
```

Comment: This is a FAQ. I'll find the dupe to close it with in a minute, but short form: `ssh ... </dev/null` will stop the SSH command from consuming all your stdin (thus leaving nothing left for future iterations of the loop).

Comment: ...the other thing you can do is to use a different FD for the file to read; ie. `done 3<file-name`, and `while read line <&3`.

Comment: thanks! I guess i wasnt searching for the right thing, because it didnt come up when i was searching on SO

Comment: `ssh -n` is another way to solve this problem.